# Не обрабатывается keyPressEvent

Tags: python, pyqt5

не могу понять почему не обрабатывается `keyPressEvent` в классе `Board`, хотя если вставить его в класс `Window`, все благополучно работает, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import random
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.board = Board(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.board)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.move(1200, 300)
        self.show()

class Board(QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_Left:
            print("Left clicked")
        elif key == Qt.Key_Right:
            print("Right clicked")
        elif key == Qt.Key_Down:
            print("Down clicked")
        elif key == Qt.Key_Up:
            print("Up clicked")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: В какой строчке оно должно обрабатываться?

Answer (score 2):

Нашел свою ошибку, необходимо было выставить `self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)` в моменте инициализации класса `Board`, который позволит отслеживать эвенты клавиатуры и мыши внутри этого класса.

Вот как это должно выглядеть:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
```